# Grabbing all options from HTML select list

Tags: php, html

I need to create a php array from a very large HTML select list. I searched for "dropdown to array" generators and programs but can't find anything. Can someone please suggest a php code that I can use to grab all options from a HTML drop-down list and output an array of them?

update: php or js. Anything that will output an array which I can copy and paste in my script.

Comment: are you creating the select with javascript or from the php script?

Comment: What is a very large number of options here? 25, 50, 200, 1000, more ?

Comment: It's clearly very large. Let's say around 200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include brackets in the select name; PHP will accept your selection as an array:

```
<?php print_r($_GET['cars']);?>

<form>
<select name="cars[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Upon postback the `print_r` outputs (depending on selection):

```
Array ( [0] => saab [1] => mercedes )
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the OP wants that.

Comment: thats for multiple select items rather than a drop down box

Comment: Thanks Mike, it's close to what I need. I'm trying to grab the name of the options not values. Values in most cases are just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**If it's javascript:**

`document.getElementById(<!--the_id_of_the_select-->)`. Options and just treat it as an array that will create and append `(document.createElement('input'), document.forms[0].appendChild(previous_item))` during the onsubmit stage of the forms process.

**Alternatively in php:**

When you do the loop for the option tags created in the select area, just do a second foreach and create a bunch of hidden elements somewhere else on the form.

Alternatively for both, instead of lots of hidden inputs (with a certain prefix), you could just create a single one that lists all the options in a csv format, or something similar